# Синхронизированный доступ потоков к одному из полей класса

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как сделать так, чтобы разные потоки смогли обращаться к одному из полей класса синхронизовано? То есть, пока один поток в Vector добавляет элемент, другой поток не смог удалить элемент из этого vector`a, пока первый поток не завершит добавление. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Vector - синхронизированная коллекция.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vector` - синхронизированная коллекция.
И действительно, вот сигнатура метода `add`:

```
public synchronized boolean add(E e)
```

А вот сигнатура метода `remove`:

```
public synchronized E remove(int index)
```

Если же вы хотите, чтобы можно было синхронизировано обращаться и к другим переменным, то используйте такие объекты:
1) для примитивных типов это `Atomic`-объекты.
2) если используете непримитив, то убедитесь, что его методы изменения состояния и получения информации о нем извне синхронизированы.